# what is the wrong wih my code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

float sum(float a,float b);

float subs(float a, float b);

float multiple(float a, float b);

float division(float a, float b);

int main()

{//main

    int a,b;

    char o ;
    cout<<"input your calculation with  operation (+,-,/,*) such as 5+6 : /n ";
    cin >> a >> o >> b ;
    switch('o')
    {
    case '+':

        sum(float a, float b);
        break;

    case '-':

        subs(float a, float b);
        break;

    case '*':

         multiple(float a, float b);
        break;

    case '/':

         division(float a, float b);
        break;

    default :
        cout << "error, try again " <<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}//main

float sum(float a,float b)
{//sum

    float total= a+b;
    return total;
}//sum

float subs(float a, float b)
{//subs

    float total=a-b;
    return total;
}//subs     

float multiple(float a, float b)
{//multiple

    float total=a*b;
    return total;
}//multiple

float division(float a, float b)
{//division

    float total=a/b;
```

Comment: what part of your code does not works as expected?  Is this homework?

Comment: I don't know.  What *is* wrong with your code?  (Is it a compiler error, a crash at runtime, or something else?)

Comment: One guess: I see nothing that would display or otherwise use the result of your operations. The return values of the functions are ignored. Did you intend to print the results?

Answer (score 7):

Superficially, you're missing a curly bracket at the end.  Operationally, your switch statement is switching on a constant, 'o', instead of the variable o.

Comment: the compiler said there is error in line 18,23,28,33 :
Expression syntax in function main()

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
switch('o')
```

to

```
switch(o)
```